# Toggle HTML Tabs on pressing ENTER

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's what I have designed:

[image]

Each one of these tabs have their own Input Form.

Upon pressing ENTER in the first input form (the one in Name), I need to toggle the tabs and set the focus to the Input Form in the next tab. This has to be repeated until I press ENTER in the last tab (Location), when the data from all the forms will be collected and submitted as a webrequest.

Here's my input form:

```html
<form><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." onsubmit="toggleFn()"></form>
```

toggleFn():

```js
function toggleFn() {
            document.getElementById("email").focus();
        }
```

Here, email is the id of the input form in the second tab but upon pressing enter, the page is just reloaded with the option *?name=whatevername*

Here's the code for the tabs:

```html
<div class="container-fluids">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Name</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">E-Mail</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Phone Number</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Location</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active"><br>
      <h4>HOME</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <p>Enter name</p>
      <form><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." onsubmit="toggleFn()">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h4>E-Mail</h4>
      <form><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail..."></form>
    </div>
.
.
.
```

I have very limited limited knowledge in Javascript and web development in general, if you can't already tell.
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap tabs, sir ?

Comment: @ErolKESKİN No, just regular HTML tabs.

Comment: Sir, you can take a look at Bootstrap-Wizard plugin. With this library you can validate your form and take the user other step, it's just like "wizard". 
Source : http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-wizard/

Comment: @PaulRunner if the answer below fixed your issue please accept as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to hide and add classes to your tabs.

```js
 var data = {};
function toggleFn(form) {
    if (form.getAttribute('name') === 'name') {
        data.name = form.name.value;
        toggleElements(1);
        setFocus('email');
    } else if (form.getAttribute('name') === 'email') {
        data.email = form.email.value;
        toggleElements(2);
        setFocus('phone');
    } else if (form.getAttribute('name') === 'phone') {
        data.phone = form.phone.value;
        toggleElements(3);
        setFocus('location');
    } else if (form.getAttribute('name') === 'location') {
        data.location = form.location.value;
        // send data via ajax here
        // reload the page
        console.log(data);
    }
    return false;
}

function setFocus(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).focus();
}

function toggleElements(menuNumber) {
    document.getElementById('menu' + menuNumber).classList.add('deactive');
    document.querySelector('.menu' + menuNumber).classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.menu' + (menuNumber + 1)).classList.add('active');
    document.getElementById('menu' + (menuNumber + 1)).classList.remove('deactive');
}
```

```css
    .deactive {
        display: none;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }
    li {
        float: left;
    }
    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

    li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .active {
        background-color: white;
    }
    .active a {
        color: #000;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluids">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu1 active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Name</a></li>
        <li class="menu2"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">E-Mail</a></li>
        <li class="menu3"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Phone Number</a></li>
        <li class="menu4"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Location</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade"><br>
            <h4>Name</h4>
            <p>Enter name</p>
            <form class="tabs" onsubmit="return toggleFn(this)" name="name"><input id="name" type="text"
                                                                                   placeholder="Name...">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade deactive"><br>
            <h4>E-mail</h4>
            <p>Enter E-mail</p>
            <form class="tabs" name="email" onsubmit="return toggleFn(this)"><input id="email" type="email"
                                                                                    placeholder="E-mail...">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade deactive"><br>
            <h4>Phone Number</h4>
            <p>Enter Phone Number</p>
            <form class="tabs" name="phone" onsubmit="return toggleFn(this)"><input id="phone" type="tel"
                                                                                    placeholder="Phone...">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade deactive"><br>
            <h4>Location</h4>
            <p>Enter Location</p>
            <form class="tabs" name="location" onsubmit="return toggleFn(this)"><input type="text" id="location"
                                                                                       placeholder="Location...">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!